# How to dissolve shared line segments together in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, line, intersection, dissolve

I have 2 features which are lines on a single layer re-projected to ESPG:2039.

[image: 2 lines]
I wish to combine them into one MultiLineString but in a way that their common part is merged to a single LineString. I'm using QGIS 3.6.2

I snapped their geometries to the grid and tried to dissolve them together. But when I add start vertices (green) and end vertices (red) to be displayed, I can see that I have 2 lines in the MultiLineString instead of 5 lines:
[image: 2 line parts instead of 5]

When I run the "intersect" tool on the lines as seperate layers, I get that they do intersect in the joint area (blue line):
[image: intersection]

How can I make the joint part be dissolved together to a single line?
Data can be found here as SHP file: http://www.filedropper.com/2lines

**UPDATE:**
I tried to use the "Remove duplicates" as suggested by Erik, but it didn't do a thing.

Comment: Take a look at the tool box, there's a tool that deletes duplicate geometries.

Comment: @Erik it didn't help unfortunately. I also get different dissolve results if I dissolve with QGIS toll or SAGA tool. But in both cases I can't get to 5 lines as needed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to merge multiple features into one  used the **Merge Selected Features** function. 
Choose all the item you want to merge, they don't need to touch each other.

[image]

Make sure that the  **Advanced Digitizing Toolbar** is on, and click on the **Merge Selected Features** function.

[image]

Know you need to choose how to merge your features. In a table with few rows it's easy, in a larger one you need to make sure that you will not lose data you need.

[image]
Now, all the rows in the table have been merged into one.

[image]